# How to fix libpapi.so.* cannot open shared object file when running (py)COMPSs with tracing?

Tags: python, distributed-computing, papi, compss, pycompss

When I try to run some COMPSs application with the tracing system activated I get the following error:

```
libpapi.so.5.3.0.0 cannot open shared object file
```

I am using ubuntu and I have installed COMPSs from the packages with apt-get. To launch the application I use:

```
runcompss --tracing --lang=python name_application.py
```

I already installed the PAPI libraries with:

```
apt-get install papi-tools libpapi-dev
```

EDIT: I am using version 1.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tracing system can not find your PAPI installation because the packages are pre-compiled.

To solve this you have two options: build and install from source the tracing package or build and install from source the whole COMPSs framework. The recommended way would be to build the whole framework in order to ensure a clean installation. However, you can just patch the tracing system if you don't want to or can't install the full dependencies stack.

**Note:** the instructions assume that the installation directory is */opt/COMPSs*

**Build all the framework (recommended)**

Make sure the previous installation is completely removed

```
sudo apt-get remove compss-* (removes only packages)
sudo apt-get purge compss-* (removes also config files)
```

Install dependencies

```
sudo apt-get update

# Build dependencies
sudo apt-get -y --force-Yes install maven subversion

# Runtime dependencies
sudo apt-get -y --force-Yes install openjdk-8-jdk graphviz xdg-utils

# Bindings-common-dependencies
sudo apt-get -y --force-Yes install libtool automake build-essential

# Python-binding dependencies
sudo apt-get -y --force-Yes install python-dev

# C-binding dependencies
sudo apt-get -y --force-Yes install libxml2-dev libboost-serialization-dev libboost-iostreams-dev csh

# Extrae dependencies
sudo apt-get -y --force-Yes install libxml2 gfortran
```

Download sources:

```
svn co http://compss.bsc.es/svn/releases/compss/1.4
```

Build and Install

```
cd ./1.4/builders
sudo -E ./buildlocal /opt/COMPSs
```

---

**Build and install only the tracing system Extrae**

Remove previous Extrae

```
sudo rm -r /opt/COMPSs/Dependencies/extrae
```

Install Extrae dependencies

```
# Extrae dependencies
sudo apt-get -y --force-Yes install libxml2 gfortran
```

Download sources:

```
svn co http://compss.bsc.es/svn/releases/compss/1.4
```

Build and install extrae

```
cd ./1.4/dependencies/extrae/
sudo ./install /opt/COMPSs/Dependencies/extrae
```